# Are “Why did you do that” and “Why have you done that” interchangeable?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

As I know, both Simple Past and Present Perfect can be used for an action that happened in the past. However, S.Past is used for an action which has a definite period of time whereas P.Perfect is used for an action which doesn't have a definite period of time. Am I right?

I'm confused about these two tenses. Can anyone explain the differences between them?
Let's take an example (Your friend - B, You - A)

> Case (1):
>   A: What **did you do** last night? Was there any fun?
>   B: No, there wasn't any fun. I already broke up with my girlfriend.
>   A: What? Why **did you do** that?
>
> Case (2): (You and your friend haven't met each other for a long time)
>   A: Hey, what **have you been doing**?
>   B: Everything is so boring. I have broken up with my girlfriend.
>   A: What? Why **have you done** that?

In Case 1, I use "Why did you do that" - (Simple Past) because I know that he broke up with his girlfriend *last night*.

However, In case 2, I use "Why have you done that" - (Present Perfect) because I don't know when he broke up with his girlfriend (Maybe yesterday or 1 week before, 2 months before,...)

What do you think? In my opinion, in most real conversation, we can use "Why did you do?" and "Why have you done?" interchangeably? Am I correct?

Comment: The simple rule I use is to ask whether the action still has consequences of importance. If it does I use the perfect, if it doesn't I use the simple past.  In your example of breaking up with a girlfriend and being unhappy because of it I would use "have you done it" because the consequences are still being felt.  If he had broken up with her last year and moved on with his life I would use the simple past.  "He broke up last year."

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can do that almost always. Although the correct usage depends upon context.

*Simple Past* is used to denote any activity in the past (distant one).

> "Why did you kick him?" is correct.

*Present Perfect* is used for an activity in the recent past. Or when the action started in the past and continues in the present.

> What have you <strike>just</strike> done?

Use of Present Perfect either with or without *just* implies something is done in recent past.

Comment: *"Recent past"* is not the criterion for using present perfect in English.